# Parsing xml with java Mahout XmlInputFormat (Hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop, xml-parsing, mahout

I have search a way to parse an xml file in Hadoop using Java

I have found [this link](http://xmlandhadoop.blogspot.co.il/)

which is showing how to use XmlInputFormat class in order to parse XML

But as someone mention in comment:
"HDFS splits files in chunks of 64mbs and program is going to lose records divided between end of a chunk and start of next one."

for exmaple file looks like :

```
<Details>
<ID> 12346 </ID>
<age> 30 </age>
<FirstName> "bla bla me"</FirstName>
<LastName> "say my name"</LastName>
</Details>
```

So what do i do in order to handle the split of xml,
 and prevent from data lost  ?

or in others word - How does it Handle when 1 xml might get split into 2 different nodes ?

Comment: I know this is not a solution, but in case it come from a DB you could replace new line char with sqoop . other way I do not know of

Comment: Unfortanatly I get those files from a know source and have no control on the data structure neather do they

Comment: I saw this in the other post also. The problem they say is with the if loop. if (!withinBlock && i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end) { return false; }.I looked into the code, now for that if block even if it hits the block boundary withinBlock will always be true until if finds the end tag right, it is going to read the file till it hits end tag. Assume split 1 and split2 has a XML split, now mapper 1 would produce the output for that XML split and mapper 2 will look for the next start tag and will proceed.In this case where is the chance of missing the records?.

Comment: I tested it in my single node cluster by making the split size as 512Kb there by creating 9 mappers and i didn't miss anything in the output.

Comment: Vignesh, did you the same example in my link ? Or build your own code for it ?

Comment: Vignesh, as you said one xml is splited in two different block/split, split 1 has the the <start> tag and half of the xml, split 2 has last half of the xml ending with </start> . how and by which key it will identify and combine these two part, my motto is generating output line for every xml records,